2 columns with the second one offset vertically
Is it possible in CSS to do a layout like this?
While keeping the order of course.


You can use display: grid to create a 2-column grid layout. Then you can use the :nth-child(2n + 2) or :nth-child(even) selector to select all items of the 2nd column. You can offset those items vertically by adding a positive margin-top and an equal negative margin-bottom to it.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.grid :nth-child(2n + 2) {
  --offset: 2.5em;
  margin-top: var(--offset);
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--offset) * -1);
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
.grid > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>



